# File Upload in Angular and Laravel API

Tags: angularjs, laravel, api

How can I stop getting 401 errors when I upload an image?

**API**

```
public function upload_office_logo(Request $request, $header_image)
{
    $header_image = $request['header_image'];
    $profileImageSaveAsName = time().".".$header_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Storage::put('public/header_image/'.$profileImageSaveAsName, 
        file_get_contents($header_image));
    
    return $header_image;
}
```

**Angular UI**

```
saveButton()
{
    let logo = this.officeModel.header_image;
    var filename = logo.split("\\", 3);
    console.log(filename[2]);
    this.officeModel.login_pw = "password123";
    this.officeService.addOfficeLogo(filename[2]).subscribe(data => {
    });
    this.officeModel.header_image = filename[2];
    this.officeService.addOffice(this.officeModel).subscribe(data => {
        this.toastr.success('Added Successfuly', 'Success');
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard-manage/office']);
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-input-grp">
    <div class="required-label">{{ setLabel("Office Logo") }}</div>
    <span class="label label-danger">{{ setLabel("Required") }}</span>
    <div class="inp-container">
        <input type="file" #fileUpload id="header_image" name="header_image" accept="image/*" 
               class="inp" [(ngModel)]="officeModel.header_image" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: A 401 status code means "Unauthorized" so look in that direction

Comment: my API worked when I tested it in thunder client, I also set the headers in angular to pass token, I'm not really sure what else is am I missing